# Multiple Process in C

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

I am a newbie to C language. I have recently come across the multi processing in C with fork() function which is written within a single main C program.

I want to know is it possible to have multiple main C programs and use the multi process concept by referring the parent_id in second main C program.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you read your `man fork`?

Comment: You could fork a new process, and the **exec**ute another program, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Or you fork a new process and let it continue doing whatever it needs to do?

Comment: And perhaps you might be interested in doing some research about [*Inter-Process Communication* (or IPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)?

Comment: Lastly please note that multi-processing in general is not a beginner subject. Learn C first, then continue onto more advanced topics.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes i mean to have two C programs fork one main programm which should refer to the child process function in second C program. If that make any sense

Comment: Read more, find examples, compile, test, see how it works. After that - send question here. fork() creates cloning of current process. Exactly the same with same values in variables.

Answer (score -1):

The `fork` system call spawns a child process at the moment it is called. You may think of it as making a perfect clone of your process, with all its state being a perfect copy of the original that it had at the moment of forking. From calling the `fork` on, each of the processes (parent and child) will continue executing on its own.

The operating system usually doesn't really make a copy of the process's memory image, but instead just pretends that they are separate, and their memory image is shared between the two instances as long as they only read it. Once one of them writes it, only then the operating system makes a copy of that memory, so that each process had its own copy independent of the other one that it could safely modify without interrupting the other process and messing up its memory.

You can call `fork` at any moment in your program, be it at the beginning of `main`, or somewhere in the middle, or even in some other function. The moment you call it, the processes will split and part ways, and each of them will execute on its own, from the place where you called `fork` and on.

There's also a way of figuring out whether your code following the `fork` is currently executing as the child process or the original parent, by checking the return value of `fork`: If you are in the parent process, `fork` returns a positive integer which is supposed to be the PID (Process Identifier) of the other, child process that has been launched at the fork. But if you're in that child process, the return value from `fork` is 0 in that case. So if your code got 0 from the `fork` call, this means that you are the child.

Of course you can launch as many child processes as you need, not just one. You can make a loop and in each turn of the loop call `fork` and note down its return value (the PID of the new child process) in some array to keep track of all the children (for each call, `fork` will return a different value for the PID).

There's [a nice video tutorial on YouTube by Jacob Sober on forking your processes in C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ss1-REMJ9GA), you may wanna check it out for more clarifications and code examples.